# finding high weight vector in Verma module

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $\frak{g}$ be a (semi-)simple lie algebra. Let $\lambda$ be a dominant integral weight. Denote $L(\lambda)$ to be the irreducible representation of highest weight $\lambda$. From BGG resolution, we know that there is a exact sequence:
$$0\to M(\omega_0\cdot \lambda)\to...\to\bigoplus_{w\in W,l(w)=1} M(w\cdot \lambda)\to M(\lambda)\to L(\lambda)\to 0.$$
It is shown that $\text{dim}(\text{Hom}(M(w\cdot \lambda),M(w'\cdot \lambda)))\le 1$ and is $1$ iff $w'\le w$ in Bruhat order.
When $\text{dim}(\text{Hom}(M(w\cdot \lambda),M(w'\cdot \lambda)))= 1$, we also have $M(w\cdot \lambda)$ is embedded into $M(w'\cdot \lambda)$.

As a result, we can fix a unique embedding of $M(w\cdot \lambda)$ to $M(\lambda)$. Every Verma module is generated by a highest weight vector so it makes sense to denote $v_{w\cdot \lambda}$ to be a highest weight vector of $M(w\cdot \lambda)$ inside $M(\lambda)$. It is unique up to a multiplicative constant.

Are ther any standard procedure to find all $v_{w\cdot \lambda}\in M(\lambda)$? Can they be written down as a formula?

So far, I just know that $v_{s_i\cdot \lambda}= f_i^{1+\lambda(h_i)}v_\lambda$ for each simple root $\alpha_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using the dot action: $$s_i\cdot\lambda=s_i(\lambda+\rho)-\rho.$$
Note that this is in fact an action, so $s_i\cdot(s_j\cdot\lambda)=(s_is_j)\cdot\lambda$. Now,
$$v_{(s_js_i)\cdot\lambda}=v_{s_j\cdot(s_i\cdot\lambda)}=f_j^{1+(s_i\cdot\lambda)(h_j)}v_{s_i\cdot\lambda}=f_j^{1+(s_i\cdot\lambda)(h_j)}f_i^{1+\lambda(h_i)}v_\lambda.$$
Now, hopefully you can generalize to $w=s_{i_1}s_{i_2}\cdots s_{i_k}$.

Comment: Is it obvious to see that those $w\cdot \lambda (h_j)$ is positive?

Comment: Not *obvious*, but it is a basic fact about the action of $W$ on root systems:  $s_i$ sends $\alpha_i\to-\alpha_i$ and permutes $\Phi^+\backslash\{\alpha_i\}$. The result follows from this.

Comment: You are very welcome.